# How to parameterize Dockerfile?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, docker

I'm creating a Dockerfile for our Spring Boot application. The application takes a couple of command line parameters. At the end of `Dockfile`:

> CMD java -jar Application.jar --bucket=bucket.list --key=lost

But is it a best practice to hardcode the values for `bucket` and `key` in the `Dockfile`?

If it is ok, then I can live with that. Otherwise, I would like to know how to parameterize the `Dockfile`.

The application will be deployed on AWS, if that opens the door for more suggestions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Docker design focused in being independent as far as possible of Host environment, including when building a Docker image. There were [a request](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/6822) to let Docker build accessing to host environmental variables but it was rejected looking for independence of host machine. There it is also commented some workaround that could fit your problem.

Anyway, what is supposed to do Application.jar? If it's an application supposed to be running inside the container (and not in building time) the correct way to launch it is using a custom script run when you start the container. There you can set your credential or any other information you wish to be accessed from a environment variable, that can be set when launching the container: `docker run -e "MYKEY=secret" -e "MYBUCKET=bucket" myuser/myapp /my/custom/script`

Comment: My application is REST application based on Spring Boot.

Comment: I have no experience with Spring (nor Spring Boot) but I think it is a way to pack your app with a webapp server (Tomcat/Jetty...), isn't it? If so, I think you should run it during Docker build but when you start the container (using a custom start script or running directly the command to start it). So you wouldn't need access those parameters in Dockerfile, but in that start script, and you could pass your parameters as environmental variables.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [environment variables or build arguments](https://vsupalov.com/docker-env-vars/).

Build arguments allow you to specify parameters that are applied at buildtime when you execute `docker build` using the `--build-arg ARG_NAME=ARG_VALUE` command line parameter.

Environment variables allow you to specify parameters that are applied at runtime when you execute `docker run` using the `-e "ENV_NAME=ENV_VALUE"` command line parameter.